# Content Script is not executing in new tab after page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Creating chrome extension which opens link in new tab and trying to click the button on newly opened tab -

I am able to open new tab using the extension but the content script is not executing on new tab.

> Manifest File

```
{
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": " New Tab Launcher",
     "description": "Create the tab and button click ",
     "version": "1.0",
     "icons": {
          "16": "icon.png",
          "48": "icon.png",
          "128": "icon.png"
     },
     "browser_action": {
          "default_popup": "popup.html"
     },
     "permissions": [
          "activeTab",
          "tabs"
          ],
     "content_scripts": [
          {
               "matches": [
                    "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
               ],
               "js": [
                    "jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js","contentScript.js"
               ],
               "run_at": "document_end"
          }
     ]
}
```

> popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('addMeetingUrl');
    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': "youtube.com"});
    }, false);
  }, false);
```

> contentScript.js

```
alert("This is test");
$(document).load(function (e) {
     alert("Testing content script" +$('#logo').text());
});
```

In above the first alert come successfully by next script does not launch.

I have tried Removing the `$(document).load` and adding `$(document).ready` both are not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

#logo could be added to the DOM after the load and ready events are fired.
Check with the debugger if I've stated is true.
If so you will need to use MutationObserver.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "run at" as it will default to "document_idle" which is usually safer option